# Deploy Spring MVC on Azure through kubenets by docker image

Tags: spring, azure, docker, model-view-controller, kubernetes

I want to deploy the Spring MVC project into Azure through Kubernetes.  I am having docker image. Please provide the guide for the steps. I am not much aware of Azure, kubernetes and docker. It will help if provide the guidance regarding step by step execution. Even what part should I learn to understand these technologies. Any good resource please?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Why not start with a more simple solution in (Azure Web Apps) and then start to learn about docker?

Comment: Sure. I will go for same. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: What else do you need? Isn't it enough to guide you to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I think if you are a new one to all the things, you'd better take a quick learn about the [Docker](https://docs.docker.com/), [Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/what-is-kubernetes/) and [Azure Kubernetes Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/intro-kubernetes). When you know what they are and what they do for you, then you can follow the [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/tutorial-kubernetes-prepare-app) to learn how to deploy your project to Azure Kubernetes Service. I think it's the necessary steps and there is not any more simple way.

Comment: Thanks Charles for ur reply. Surely I will do the same. Thanks for sharing the links

Comment: @Gurudas So what is the result? Do you finish deploying your project?